# Invertible matrix whos square is not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Of course, this scenario is impossible for finite dimensional matrices. I am trying to understand what it means for an unbounded linear operator to have a well defined inverse, but the square of its inverse does not exist. It's pretty easy to find examples of this happening. Take the matrix

$$M_{nm}=2\delta_{nm}-\delta_{n+1m}-\delta_{n-1m}$$

Defined for $n,m\geq 1$. This has the inverse $M^{-1}_{nm}=\text{min}(n,m)$. The square of the inverse obviously diverges and so does not exist. The square goes like $M^{-2}_{nm}\sim nm/3*N$ where $N$ is the size of the matrix.

What does this mean for the matrix $M^2$? Does $M^2$ somehow pick up a zero eigenvalue that $M$ didn't have?

**Edit 1:** I'd like to say also that $M$ itself can be said to have zero eigenvalues, with eigensequence $a_n=n$, but if we define everything to be in the Hilbert space $l^2$ of finite norm sequences $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|^2<\infty$, then those sequences don't belong to the space, hence why we are able to define an inverse.

Perhaps theres something about the incompatibility of the linear operator $M$ with the Hilbert space?

**Edit 2:** After playing around with this a little more, I've come to the conclusion that the operator $M^{-1}_{nm}=\text{min}(n,m)$ maps $l^2$ vectors to a different space (that I don't know), in the same sense that the derivative operator takes $x^{1/2}$ out of $L^2([0,1])$. It just so happens that one of the problem $l^2$ vectors is $a^{(m)}_{n}=\delta_{mn}$, hence why the norm $|M^{-1}a^{(m)}|^2=M^{-2}_{mm}=\infty$.

If this is the case, in what sense can we define $M^{-1}$? do we need to use a different basis other than $a^{(m)}_n$?

Comment: On what space is the matrix operating?

Comment: On the space of sequences with finite norm as described in my edit.